# Search on non-text column in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a sqlalchemy model:

```
class Multicast(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "multicast"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    addr = Column(Inet)
    name = Column(Unicode(65))
```

I need to make search by "addr" field.
I could not do it in this way:

```
class MulticastView(ModelView):
    column_searchable_list = ('name', 'addr',)
    column_filters = ('name', )
    model = Multicast
```

Because i had an Exception: Can only search on text columns. Failed to setup search for "addr". How can i make this search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some solution. I overrided get_list method in MulticastView. I copied all source code from ModelView and added a line in search criteria code:

```
filter_stmt.append(func.text(Multicast.addr).like(stmt))
```

It works!

Comment: Can you add full example ?

Comment: I can't, because It was long time ago. But i created a pull request for flask-admin and it had been merged. So, you don't have to write you own code for this because it already works in flask-admin. You can find the PR here https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/pull/1114

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to modify the allowed_search_types for the MulticastView class:

```
class MulticastView(ModelView):
    allowed_search_types = (
        mongoengine.StringField,
        mongoengine.URLField,
        mongoengine.EmailField,
        mongoengine.Inet
    )
    ...
```