# Flask admin add referencefield to Column_searchable_list problem

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Can not add ReferenceField to column_searchable_list

> Exception: Can only search on text columns. Failed to setup search for
>   < mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField object at 0x7f093478e090>

Needs Implementation or can be overridden by any trick ?

[Search on non-text column in flask-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009081/search-on-non-text-column-in-flask-admin)

**EDIT:**

> ```
> allowed_search_types = (
>     StringField,
>     URLField,
>     EmailField,
>     ReferenceField
> )
> ```

this does work only if fully type reference string, it does not work as "contains" operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/pull/1796
By this PR I fixed this issue